# Modbus compile error Arduino

Tags: arduino, protocol, modbus

I have Code for Mod bus Library as below. I have Gone through lots of forum. How to assign device ID, slave address, length using below library function:

```
#include <SimpleModbusSlave.h>
#define  LED 9  
enum 
{     

  ADC_VAL,     
  PWM_VAL,        
  HOLDING_REGS_SIZE // leave this one
};

unsigned int holdingRegs[HOLDING_REGS_SIZE]; 
void setup()
{
  modbus_configure(&Serial, 9600, SERIAL_8N2, 1, 2, HOLDING_REGS_SIZE, holdingRegs);    
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  modbus_update();
  holdingRegs[ADC_VAL] = analogRead(A0); // update data to be read by the master to adjust the PWM
  analogWrite(LED, holdingRegs[PWM_VAL]>>2); // constrain adc value from the arduino master to 255
}
```

I am getting Error has.

```
SimpleModbusSlaveArduino.cpp: In function 'void setup()':
SimpleModbusSlaveArduino:79: error: 'SERIAL_8N2' was not declared in this scope
```

Let me know how to resolve issue.

Comment: Link to the library?

Comment: Its being already added, How to link library??

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear - could you give us a link to the library you're using? It is difficult to diagnose your problem otherwise.

Comment: @AMPS  Just FYI.  There is now a stack dedicated to Arduino http://arduino.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Open up SimpleModbusSlave.c.  Check the format of modbus_configure() matches what you have.

Open up SimpleModbusSlave.h. Check the define for SERIAL_8N2 exists.

I'm guessing it should be

modbus_configure(9600, 1, 2, HOLDING_REGS_SIZE);